# Add a scatterplot to this D3 line chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, multiline, linechart

D3 noob here, I managed to make a multi-line chart and I would like to add a data points to the lines. That way, I could hover on individual data points and show a tool tip. I think I can handle the tool tip part if someone can help me add data points to my line.

Here's my code in a pastebin: http://pastebin.com/F8L5gS4D

I seriously couldn't get it to run in a codepen or get it to show up on stack overflow without losing all its formatting.

here's the data I'm working with: http://pastebin.com/GyjMwqGb But I restructure it in the javascript with d3.nest(), sorting it by School.

Any help would be much appreciated. Maybe even just point me to a good guide.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Your `forEach` where you do `svg.append` is not the D3 way.
Go thru some tutorials and learn about `d3.selectAll()`

- https://square.github.io/intro-to-d3/data-binding/
- http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/binding-data

I would then use hardcoded data before reading from CSV.

Finally when you read CSV usually you put the code to add SVG elements in the body of `d3.csv`

```
d3.csv("apdata.csv", function(error, data) {
   data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.Wk = +d.Wk;
      d.Rk = +d.Rk;
   svg.selectAll(...)
     .append()
     ...
 });
```

HTH